# Bootstrap 3.0 - Static table horizontal size in the panel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I can not understand why the size of the nested table is static large then the panel decreases with the size of the browser. What can I do about it?

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <table class="table">
        ...
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/88846
Screenshoot: https://db.tt/JDhkB7oQ

Comment: I find it workign fine.. which browser did you test it on?

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi You have tried to make the browser very narrow? The table starts to get out of the panel. I was tried on Firefox 24 and Chrome 30.0.1599.101. Screenshoot: https://db.tt/JDhkB7oQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want your table to be responsive use .table-responsive class int eh div around table, this will create a horizontal scroll bar so that your contents are not chopped out.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table">
...
 </table>
 </div>
```

You can also try for other responsive tables solutions like http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/